# How to stop puppeteer overwriting each screenshot

Tags: google-chrome, automation, puppeteer

I wrote a simple script to take a screenshot each day but when I run tests instead of saving 2 different screenshots it overwrites the previous screenshot with a new screenshot. How do I stop this?

My code:

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    const SELECTOR = ".octicon";
    (async () => {
    let screenshotNumber = 0;
    async function main() {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
            executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google 
    Chrome',
            slowMo:10
        });
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto('https://tvguideuk.net/channel/film4');
      await page.screenshot({ path: `octicon-${screenshotNumber}.jpg`, fullPage: 
     true })
      screenshotNumber++;
      //await page.waitForTimeout(15000); // wait for 15 seconds
      await browser.close()
      //screenshotNumber++;

    }
      main();
    })();
```

Any advice would help. Many Thanks.

Comment: Are you running the script multiple times? Variables don't persist from one run to the next, so either write the number to file or other persistent storage, read through the existing screenshots to figure the next number out, or use a datetime stamp or random number that won't collide.

Comment: Yes I want to set the script to repeat itself once every couple days, I am writing the number to file and I have used ScreenshotNumber ++ so that each new screenshot will be numbered differently but instead each new screenshot just overwrites the last, taking its name, in this case, it constantly saves as “octicon_0” how do I get it to save octicon_1, octicon_2, octicon_3, etc with each new screenshot?